# TypeError '_Environ' object is not callable

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

this show up  everytime i try launch my discord bot. i tried to google but there wasnt anything good code is
bot.run(os.environ('TOKEN'))

Comment: Please share your code in code blocks please

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[os.environ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) is a dictionary object. Use `os.environ['TOKEN']` or `os.environ.get('TOKEN')`

Comment: AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: That means there is no environment variable named TOKEN.

Comment: instead of token i put my discordb

Comment: discord bot token*

Comment: Environment variables are typically used when you use configuration files such as dotenv or hosting service such as Heroku. If you use your bot locally, then there isn't much use of using `os.environ`. You can directly use `bot.run(<your token>)` where `<your token>` is replaced by your token. However, if you post your code ALWAYS REMOVE all mentions of token.

Answer (score 0):

You should first import `loadenv` from a module called `dotenv` and than you can get the token from `.env`

`pip install python-dotenv` That how to install it using pip.

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv["token"] # load_dotenv.get('token') work the same as the first one
```